# phpmyadmin import & overwrite table

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

this has been annoying me for weeks and i cant find a proper solution.
im running a VPS
centos 7 (and aapanel which has no relevance)
php 7.4
mysql 5.7
phpmyadmin 5.0

ive gone into phpmyadmin, exported a table, updated 5000 rows, and i want to import and overwrite the old data into the same table.
the 'browse' and import is not an option(as vps error 503/low ram to load) and so ive tried to add it by SQL tab:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/database/links.csv' 
INTO TABLE links 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

with permission denied

*yes, ive added

```
[MySQLi]
mysqli.allow_local_infile = On
```

to my.conf and even tried to add to php.ini
and restarted apache and even tried removing LOCAL(Saw that on stack too) with no avail*

does anyone have an updated version, or know of a solid solution to this annoying, but should be easy solution?

**EDIT**

root user = fixes issue for permission denied... but...

LOAD DATA INFILE

error
#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

**--secure-file-priv has been removed from my.conf and apache restarted and error still appears**

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

error
#2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

**mysqli.allow_local_infile = On is still in my.conf**

file has full permissions(777) and tried changing owner (www/root/mysql)

Comment: what is **full path** for your `links.csv` on server?  You probably have error path in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '...'`

Comment: ive edited my post, but the path is correct as /database/ is in root dir

Answer (score 0):

Carefully read difference between `LOCAL` and non-`LOCAL` versions of `LOAD DATA` command: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html#load-data-local

You need to check state of `secure_file_priv` config variable for non-`LOCAL` version of command:

```
mysql> select @@secure_file_priv;
+-----------------------+
| @@secure_file_priv    |
+-----------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+-----------------------+
```

File must be located here.

For `LOCAL` version of the command you must check permission of client to read such file. In case of phpmyadmin it will be **php as client**.

In both cases double check that mysql server or php both have enough permissions **to enter directory** and **read file**. The easiest way is to login under system user for mysql or php and just try to read file:

```sh
sudo -u mysql_or_php_user /bin/bash
```

or

```sh
su -s /bin/bash mysql_or_php_user
```

then

```
head /database/links.csv
```